# mysql php return json only when one row nothing when many

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing PHP code on an online serveur in php 7.2.4. I want to get data of the database on this server.

But when i have only one row returned by sql query : json is ok
Minimum two rows and php return nothing (code 200 but empty response)

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  require_once "connexion.php";

  $sql = "select id,title,image from em0hb_yendifvideoshare_videos limit 1";
  $res = $conn->query($sql);
  $conn->close();
  $i=0;
  while($i < $res->num_rows){
    $res->data_seek($i);
    $row = $res->fetch_row();
    $videos [] = [
        "id" => $row[0],
        "title" => $row[1],
        "image" => $row[2]
    ];
    $i++;
  }
  echo(json_encode($videos));
?>
```

Comment: I think you should remove the unnecessary space here: `$videos []`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to seek, etc... iterating over on the results is way more simple:

The [`fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) function moving the pointer automatically.

```
while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $videos[] = $row;
}
```

Edit:
I guess your real problem is the `$conn->close();` part, because you close the connection before you fetch the results.

Comment: <?php
  require_once "connexion.php";
 
  $sql = "select id,title,image from em0hb_yendifvideoshare_videos limit 2";
  $res = $conn->query($sql);
  $conn->close();
  while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
   $videos[] = $row;
  }
  echo(json_encode($videos));
?>

Comment: Edited my answer (my bet is the $conn->close())

Comment: result is stored in $res so connection can be closed. Tested with close a the end of code and same problem

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : i must use utf8_encode on strings from the db before json_encode the data